# How to search for words in a Corpus?

Tags: r, tm, corpus

Suppose I have a data frame that has 2 columns: "question_no" and "question_text"
"question_no" just goes from 1 to the `length(data$question_no)` and "question_text" has questions.
I want to categorize the questions that have words "in order" and "summarize".
So far I've come up with these few lines of codes:

```
questions<-Corpus(VectorSouce(data$question_text))
questions<-tm_map(questions,tolower)
questions<-tm_map(questions,stripWhiteSpace)
spesificQuestion<- ifelse(Corpus=="in order"|Corpus=="summarize",pquestions, others=
```

**I know it is a pretty awful set of codes, i just wanted show my intention.**

What should I do to select certain words from a corpus?

Comment: Maybe check out `grep`?

Comment: Is it possible for the `question_text` entries to include words aside from "summarize" and "in order" i.e. are you looking only for full or partial matches? Do you want to create a new column that specifies whether or not your conditions are met?

Comment: For example:" 'summarize' the second paragraph of the first passage." Assume I have these kinds of questions(or instructions) and I want to define whether they have "summarize" or "in order" in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this data frame:

```
   df <- data.frame(
   question_no = c(1:6),
   question_text = c("put these words in order","summarize the  paper","nonsense",
   "summarize the story", "put something in order", "nonsense")
   )

    question_no            question_text
       1             put these words in order
       2             summarize the paper
       3             nonsense
       4             summarize the story
       5             put something in order
       6             nonsense
```

You could try...

```
     library(stringr)
     library(dplyr)
     mutate (df, condition_met = if_else(str_detect(df$question_text,"\\bsummarize\\b|\\bin order\\b"), "Yes", "No"))
```

Which produces...

```
  question_no            question_text         condition_met
       1         put these words in order           Yes
       2         summarize the paper                Yes
       3         nonsense                           No
       4         summarize the story                Yes
       5         put something in order             Yes
       6         nonsense                           No
```

`stringr::str_detect` creates a logical vector equal to the length of the first argument. It searches each element in the original vector to see if it contains your desired string (or strings). Note that I'm checking for the word "summarize" and the words "in order" to avoid matching things like "un-summarize". If that doesn't matter to you, you can convert the matching string to `".*summarize.*|.*in order.*"`  Using `if_else` allows you to turn the `TRUE` and `FALSE` into whatever you want. In this case I did "yes" and "no".

`dplyr::mutate` creates a new column named however you want. Leaving the values of TRUE and FALSE will allow you to see how many or what proportion of entries contain the strings you're interested in. If that's what you want then take out the `if_else` argument, i.e....

```
     mutate (df, condition_met = str_detect(df$question_text,"\\bsummarize\\b|\\bin order\\b"))
```